# Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm following [this tutorial](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/detecting-arrays-vs-objects-in-javascript.html) to "detect" if a unique number is in an array object. This number is a string.

I'm used to `detect` in Ruby on Rails so I look for the equivalent in React (JavaScript):

**ES6:**

```
...


// this will be "data" in "this.props.data"
data = [
 {
   id: 1,
   order_id: "44",
   name: "Some order number name",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    order_id: "65",
    ...,
  }
]

  // let num = "44"; Just for this example

  renderCreditNote(num){
    if (num instanceof this.props.data) {
      return num.map(function(p){
        return p.order_id
      });
    }
  }

  render(){
   return({this.renderCreditNote().bind(this)})
  }

...
```

In reality, this will look like this: `this.renderCreditNote(this.state.num).bind(this)`

So if this `num` is in the Array, display only that array. Am I doing this the right way? The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable

Comment: Looks like you need [array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), not `instanceof` here.

Comment: how does array.includes handle arrays/objects? I know if you have a list of integers it works, but does it handle checking nested objects?

Comment: Sylar, if I am understnding right, `this.props.data` is an array of what? And you want to 1. check if `num` is in that array, and if it is return the `order_id` of it?

Comment: Im on mobile. Ill update question with what i have in an hour

Comment: Ok I have made an edit to show what I have. So if order id is 44, return only that array.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Ruby, but based on the description of `detect` it seems you are looking for [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in JavaScript. `.find` iterates over an array - if it finds the item you are looking for it returns it and stops iterating, if it does not find anything `undefined` is returned.

So for example:

```
  renderCreditNote(num){
    return this.props.data.find(function(p){
      return num === p.order_id;
    });
  }
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ykt9ze3/

Some ES6 prettification:

```
  renderCreditNote(num){
    return this.props.data.find(p => num === p.order_id);
  }
```

Be aware that this isn't completely supported in slightly older browsers, I know from experience IE11 doesn't have it. However it is definitely worth the polyfill.

About the blog you linked - without going into prototypical inheritance, `instanceof` basically returns true/false if the input is of the data structure. In the blog you linked they are detecting whether or not the input is an object or an array - but only so they can take different actions depending on that input. So if it's an object they simply return the field on that object, if it's an array they iterate over the array with `.map` and return all the names of those objects in that array.

Edit to check render method:

```
  render(){

   return(<div>{JSON.stringify(this.renderCreditNote().bind(this))}</div>)
  }
```

Comment: I see. I'll try this and report.

Comment: I now get `ncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check render menthod`

Comment: That is a react error - the render method is expecting a JSX/html element but you are returning a raw javascript object. Try what I linked in my edit and see if that displays anything.

Comment: you've lost me now - you only have one array, `data`.

Comment: Yes with many objects. Ok, if match, remove all other objects and leave one object in the array so that I can iterate over. Makes sense? If not I'll just do an ajax to the server and grab the array needed

Comment: Ok try this: `{ [this.renderCreditNote("44").bind(this)] }`

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to pass a function to instance of in the right hand side. Try and do `this.props.data.constructor`

Comment: That gets rid of the error but Im not getting the order id which is "44".

Comment: Add an else statement to return "44". Your question didn't say anything about this.

Comment: Ok ill try and respond later. Thanks